# html side-by-side tables row height

Tags: html, html-table

I am working on an HTML page where I need to display two tables side-by-side. Height of the rows of second table will be dynamic as the data in it will be generated as the program will run whereas the first table has the fixed length of data. Now I am stuck in aligning both table rows. If data length of second table grows, then its row will not be aligned to the corresponding row in first table. May be the third row of second table comes in front of fifth row of first table.

The **constraint** here is **these are two separate tables** and **cannot be merged** into a single table.

For both tables font-size = 12px and padding = 5 pixel. Can someone suggest me a formula which can calculate the height of row of second table, so that same height can be set for corresponding row in first table (with help of some method) and both rows can be aligned to each other.

Below is the formula which came into my mind but did not work -

height of row in first table = (12*number of lines in row of second table) + 5 + 5.

I have already a method which calculates the number of lines in the row of second table.

Comment: This isn't possible, I think, without using JavaScript.

Comment: (12*number of lines in row of second table) - what about spaces between lines?

Comment: why not simulating two tables with 2 tds in ONE table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution !!!

Each line in the row of second table is consuming 14 pixels. 12 px for line height and 2 px for space, I guess.

Hence, the formula will be -

```
height of row in first table = (14*number of lines in row of second table) + 5 + 5
```

I applied this formula and now the rows of two tables are synchronized.

How I got this -
I created a duplicate HTML page and created a number of lines of data in each row in an increamenting order in second table.
Like -> 1st row = 2 lines, 2nd row = 3 lines, 3rd row = 4 lines and so on.
Then manually set the pixels of rows of first table to align them with their counterparts. I found that they are following a pattern and are at a difference of 14 pixels.

Issue resolved :)